# Сложности при обучении нейросети для распознования тематики текста

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, классификация, классификация-текста

Мне нужно обучить  нейросеть для распознование текста только определённой тематики (к примеру спорт). В таком случае нейросеть должна предсказывать относиться ли тематика текста к спорту. Не понятно следующее:

- Какой должен быть dataset для её обучения?
- Примеры текстов о    спорте, и примеры случайных текстов других
  тематик?
- Как-то иначе?

Comment: Как насчёт ключевых слов о спорте чем больше вхождений тем больше вероятность что НС правильно распознала смысл.

Comment: @hays Не подходит, в моём случае проще и быстрее использовать полноценные тексты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы постарался подобрать обучающую выборку, где половина текстов относилась бы к спортивной тематике, а вторая половина - тексты на самые разные темы, которые не относятся к тексту. На сбалансированных обучающих данных легче строить классифицирующие модели.

PS а почему бы не построить сразу мультиклассовую (multiclass & multilabel) модель, которая будет предсказывать степень вероятности принадлежности текста к разным тематикам (классам) одновременно?

PPS методика `doc2vec` как раз была придумана для подобного рода задач - советую поискать в сети примеры её использования.

Comment: Я примерно так это себе и представлял. Насчёт doc2cec обязательно почитаю.

Comment: @СергейАндреев, https://blog.francium.tech/content-based-text-classification-with-doc2vec-and-tensorflow-efd1dd4f02a8

Comment: И да, в своей моделе я использую multiclasses классификацию, но проблема в том что  тексты которые будут подорваться на вход обученной нейросети могут не относиться не к одной из категорий на которые обучалась нейросеть, и это нужно учитывать (нейросеть должна предсказывать что текст не относиться не к одной из известных ей категорий )

Comment: Можно попробовать подготовить данные для дополнительного класса (НЕИЗВЕСТНЫЙ) и обучать модель вместе с этими данными